# ANTLR4 and chess UCI parser problems with simple grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I want to define simple grammar for UCI protocol but I have some problems with it.

I want parse such line:

```
id name hello world
```

Nothing complex I wrote such grammar:

grammar s01_uci;

```
id_name
    : 'id' SPACE 'name' SPACE ID_NAME
    ;

SPACE
    : ' '
    ;

ID_NAME
    : .+?
    ;

LINE_END
    : '\r\n'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ;
```

My Pycharm Antlr4 plugin shows that only 'id name h' is parsed rest is not visible to parser. Why it happens - wrong lexer rules?

It look simple that I should match token but maybe I define too much token or not enough in Lexer - I have not idea how to improve it after reading many articles.

Some example of lines to be parsed (input is lines not file):

```
id name Stockfish 10 64 BMI2
id author T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott

option name Debug Log File type string default
option name Contempt type spin default 24 min -100 max 100
option name Analysis Contempt type combo default Both var Off var White var Black var Both
option name Threads type spin default 1 min 1 max 512
option name Hash type spin default 16 min 1 max 131072
option name Clear Hash type button
option name Ponder type check default false
option name MultiPV type spin default 1 min 1 max 500
option name Skill Level type spin default 20 min 0 max 20
option name Move Overhead type spin default 30 min 0 max 5000
option name Minimum Thinking Time type spin default 20 min 0 max 5000
option name Slow Mover type spin default 84 min 10 max 1000
option name nodestime type spin default 0 min 0 max 10000
option name UCI_Chess960 type check default false
option name UCI_AnalyseMode type check default false
option name SyzygyPath type string default <empty>
option name SyzygyProbeDepth type spin default 1 min 1 max 100
option name Syzygy50MoveRule type check default true
option name SyzygyProbeLimit type spin default 7 min 0 max 7
uciok
```

Comment: This input is so trivial, you don't need a parser for that. Simply split input lines by line breaks, strip `option name` and take the rest of the line as your `ID_NAME`.

Comment: I done trivial parser maybe next step will be ANTLR4 but it is not need now (no sense to improve speed here).